# VBA if value in column A then replace in column B

Tags: excel, vba, find-replace

im currently using this VBA code that looks at values in column A in Sheet2 and if found it removes this value in column A in Sheet1.

```html
Sub ifFoundReplace()
Dim i As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).row
        ws1.Columns(1).Replace ws2.Cells(i, "A") & " ", "", xlPart
        ws1.Columns(1).Replace " " & ws2.Cells(i, "A"), "", xlPart
    Next i
End Sub
```

So, on Sheet1 in column A I have:

a white

b black

d white

c orange

On Sheet2 in column A I have:

a

b

d

c

When I run the VBA, as a result I have White, Black, Orange, White, without a, b, c, d, as these values are in Sheet2.

But if I have these in Sheet1 in column A:

white a

black b

white d

orange c

the code does not work properly.

Cheers

Comment: basically I would like to remove all exact matches, so only "a".

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex which would be able to identify if the string is found with white space, start of line or end of line surrounding it. Something like this.

```
Dim regex As Object, str As String
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regex
  .Pattern = "(^|[[:blank:]])[" + :: VALUE FROM SHEET 1:: + "]($|[[:blank:]])"
  .Global = True
End With

val = ::value of cell you are evaluating::
newVal = regex.Replace(val , "")
```

Then just put newVal in the cell you are evaluating. I'm at work so I can't test this but hopefully this sends you down the right path.